# Elephant Park within a day trip from Bangkok

Tags: thailand, nature-and-wildlife, bangkok

I'm familiar with elephant parks in Northern Thailand, near Chiang Mai. Are there any good elephant parks (preferably with humane treatment) within a day trip's distance from Bangkok?

Comment: I don't know about elephant conservation parks, but you can see elephants in the wild in Khao Yai National Park (~200 km from Bangkok).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I stayed in Hua Hin about 2 years ago, and went on a trip to see elephants right outside of town.  I believe the park at this link is the correct one: http://www.thailand-huahin.com/huahin-elephants.htm

Hua Hin is approximately 200km south of Bangkok. I cannot attest to the treatment of the elephants, but everything appeared on the up and up when I was there.  I remember this park as being family friendly and enjoyable.

I hope this helps. If you need any further information, just ask!